# Getting list elements in original order

Tags: python, for-loop

My current code:

```
>>> sent=['attachment', '(1.', '=', '+EDT)', 'Details']
>>> [w[1:] for w in sent if w.startswith(('(', '+'))]+[w for w in sent if not w.startswith(('(', '+'))]
```

output:

```
['1.', 'EDT)', 'attachment', '=', 'Details']
```

I want it like this:

```
['attachment','1.', '=','EDT)', 'Details']
```

maintaining the original order.

I don't want to use `re.replace`, I just want to use `w.startswith()`.

Comment: If you describe in plain language what you want to do, it will be easier to help you. But anyway, `str.lstrip()` seems to be what you want.

Comment: str.lstrip() can't help me in this situation :'(

Comment: thank you so much DSM. this is great.

Answer (score 2):

To use `startswith()` while maintaining the original order you need to perform the operation inside one list comprehension. We can do that using a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
sent = ['attachment', '(1.', '=', '+EDT)', 'Details']
print([w[1:] if w.startswith(('(', '+')) else w for w in sent])
```

**output**

```
['attachment', '1.', '=', 'EDT)', 'Details']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work since it is building 2 lists; the first one contains those which start with `+` or `(`, and the second one those which don't; these are then catenated in order.

---

Your code fixed and using a conditional expression properly would read

```
>>> sent = ['attachment', '(1.', '=', '+EDT)', 'Details']
>>> [ w[1:] if w.startswith(('(', '+')) else w for w in sent ]
['attachment', '1.', '=', 'EDT)', 'Details']
```

---

However a better and more powerful option would be to use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) here

```
>>> import re
>>> sent = ['attachment', '(1.', '=', '+EDT)', 'Details']
>>> [ re.sub(r'^[+(]', '', w) for w in sent ]
['attachment', '1.', '=','EDT)', 'Details']
```

The *regular expression* `^[+(]` matches the beginning of string followed by exactly 1 `+` or `(`; whatever is matched is replaced with an empty string `''`.

---

On the other hand if you really want removing *all* leading `(` and `+` characters, no matter how many, use the `.lstrip`:

```
>>> sent = ['attachment', '(1.', '=', '+EDT)', 'Details']
>>> [ w.lstrip('+(') for w in sent ]
['attachment', '1.', '=', 'EDT)', 'Details']
```

This will also replace `+(++++((((foo` with `foo` which might or might not be what you wanted.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't want to import the `re` module for this - they want to do it with built-in methods. :)